# memcached restart with active sessions causes request to hang for 30-40 seconds and session is killed

Tags: php, session

I was doing some testing with memcached using php sessions.

The following steps cause problems.

1. Start memcache
2. Login to application which creates a session
3. Restart memcache
4. Try to navigate to another page
5. Browser hangs for 30 seconds and logs out
6. Requests after logging in again take 30 seconds but works. Randomly it stops taking 30 seconds to perform actions and is back to normal speed

What is the cause of this odd behavior

Sometimes I get the following error:

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message:  Unknown: Failed to write session data (memcache). Please verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct (tcp://10.181.16.192:11211?persistent=1&weight=1&timeout=1&retry_interval=15)

Filename: Unknown

Line Number: 0

EDIT:

If I restart memcache then apache the problem does not occur

I noticed TCP connections change to CLOSE_WAIT when restarting memcached.

But if I restart memcache and apache back to back without delay then it solves the problem.

It seems like there is some sort of bug in the way php handles connections to memcache where it doesn't recognize the connection is valid anymore and causes the issues described.

[root@php-pos-web ~]# netstat -natp | grep '11211'

```
tcp        1      0 10.181.16.33:58722          10.181.16.192:11211         CLOSE_WAIT  7574/httpd          
tcp      205      0 10.181.16.33:58753          10.181.16.192:11211         ESTABLISHED 7583/httpd          
tcp        1      0 10.181.16.33:58745          10.181.16.192:11211         CLOSE_WAIT  7578/httpd          
tcp        1      0 10.181.16.33:58749          10.181.16.192:11211         CLOSE_WAIT  7573/httpd
```

Comment: Attach by debugger and see what is holding the request, there is no fortune tellers here so far.

Comment: Updated with more information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a bug in starting in 3.0.4 of the memcache pecl extension. This does not happen on the latest stable release (2.2.7). I have [reported this bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=67534%5C) to the team. I think it has something to do with session locking. This bug does not occur in memcached extension.